# Grails 2.2.3 - is there a `-y` command line option?

Tags: grails, command-line, build-process, command-line-interface

I have a `Grails 2.2.3` application and I'm using `TeamCity 7.1.3` as my build server. So far, everything was working like a charm until one fine day I decided to update a plugin in my `BuildConfig.groovy` file.

Locally, I was of course able to update the plugin - but I was asked to confirm the plugin update, which is not a problem if it's locally and I'm the **master of the cli**, but it is a HUGE PROBLEM if this confirmation dialog pops up at the buildserver where I have no access to the command line during the build step.

Is there a **commandline option** like `-y` where I can tell the system to force the `y` parameter if asked for confirmation? Something like `grails refresh-dependencies -y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `--non-interactive` while issuing commands.

For example: `grails compile --non-interactive`

To bypass the manual interaction, mainly useful in build servers as in your case.